# Multiple Selects in a form, how to give each a unique name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with multiple rows, each rows has a select box.  How can I give each a unique name so that I end up with a param value for the select on each row.

Currently the params only gives the selected value of the last row.

Here is what I have:

```
<% @my_fields.each do |field| %>
  <tr><td><%= form.collection_select(:ServiceTypeID, @service_levels, :ServiceTypeID, :ServiceName) %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

There are ten rows in my test data.

Currently I only get one param which is for the last select, I guess i need to uniquely name each select, ideally with field.FieldID which is unique.  I can't work out where/how to name the collection_select.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `collection_select` method ([source](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)):

> collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method,
>   text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})

You can override the select `name` attribute in the `html_options` hash:

```
<% @my_fields.each_with_index do |field, index| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= form.collection_select(:ServiceTypeID, @service_levels, :ServiceTypeID, :ServiceName, {}, { name: "my_name_#{index}" }) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```